# How to define Assembly Folders for an application?

Tags: .net-2.0

How do I define the Assembly folder for an Application correctly?
I tried to use the registry Key:
HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/.NET Framework/AssemblyFolders/App-Name
and use the (Default) to set this to the path where the assemblies are located.

Some time ago this worked fine, but as I compiled a new Version and deployed it to a PC it wont work any more.

Do I have to add something else or missed any task?

Comment: Why are you having to touch this registry setting?

Comment: 'cause I want to keep my libs on a defined place

Comment: Why do you want to keep them in one place ?

Comment: This could be a typo, but check that ".NETFramework" in your registry path has no space in it.

Answer (score 1):

Those registry keys are only used by visual studio for loading the references list and for helping with hint paths. Applications built on .Net use assembly loading rules which check for assemblies in the GAC, the application's private bin path, or some other subfolder under the private bin path. The .Net runtime does not use the registry to resolve assemblies at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add a reference on a machine that running 64-bit OS, than you need to add your App-Name under following registry key.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\App-Name.

It's exactly like in your example, except that you need to add Wow6432Node key between SOFTWARE and Microsoft.